# Get distance of route based on google url using google api

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-api

I want to get `distance`, eventually other informations requesting via `google API`. I got google `API key`. As you see below i have common template which i fill out during program runs, it could have waypoints in it and travel modes. What should be google API request to get distance and other information let's say via `JSON`?

```
String mapsUrl = $"https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin={origin}&destination={destination}&waypoints={torun}|{lodz}&travelmode={travelMode}&dir_action=navigate";
```

Answer (score 0):

From Google documentation at [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) - you will need to use the Distance Matrix API.

The request will be something like:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=Washington,DC&destinations=New+York+City,NY&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Replace the YOUR_API_KEY placeholder with your key.

The response will be a Json in this format:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "New York, NY, USA" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Washington, DC, USA" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "225 mi",
                  "value" : 361715
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 hours 49 mins",
                  "value" : 13725
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

if you dont have the correct API key do as following:

1. Login into your [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://cloud.google.com/console/google/maps-apis/overview)
2. Add your project and add the API's. Please note that the Distance
   Matrix API is not free.
3. Once you do so you will obtain your API key.

***Edit***

If you need to add multiple way-points you need to use a different API see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) Maps JavaScript API Directions Service. Its the same as Google Map in a nutshell.

It allows you to add an array of way-points. Again its not free - its a PAYG service.

The `DirectionsResult` object will contain the `Directions Legs`(distance in meters)

Comment: 1. What about if there are waypoints? 2. I got google API - what is the price when using/or how its calculate this Distance Matrix API ?

Comment: All the information you need is in their documentation: price, how to use it etc. The DM Api from what I can see its based on two points.

Comment: so no way to measure distance based on more than two points? :O